Are there other methods to achieve the result in this format?
(a c + b d)^2 + (a d - b c)^2 // Factor

get the result:
(a^2 + b^2) (c^2 + d^2)

How can I achieve the output in this format as follows?
(a c + b d)^2 + (a d - b c)^2 == (a^2 + b^2)  (c^2 + d^2)


My approach is like this. Are there other methods to achieve the result in this format?
Print["(a c+b d\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\()\), \(2\)]\)+(a d-b \
c\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\()\), \(2\)]\)==", (a  c + b  d)^2 + (a  d - 
     b  c)^2 // Factor]



Why not something like this? https://i.sstatic.net/n1W1hsPN.png  i.e. f = (a  c + b  d)^2 + (a  d - b  c)^2 followed by f == Factor[f]  Did I overlook something in what you wanted?

Or # == Factor[#] &[(a c + b d)^2 + (a d - b c)^2]

I understand this as a question about displaying the result.  One can inject the simplified expression into a held one:
expr = With[{expr = (a^2 + b^2) (c^2 + d^2) // Factor}, Hold[(a c + b d)^2 + (a d - b c)^2 == expr]]
(* Hold[(a c + b d)^2 + (a d - b c)^2 == (a^2 + b^2) (c^2 + d^2)] *)

Then one can release the hold to evaluate it:
ReleaseHold@expr // Simplify
(* True *)


Alternatively, Inacticate Equal:
expr = Inactivate[(a c + b d)^2 + (a d - b c)^2 == Factor[(a c + b d)^2 + (a d - b c)^2], Equal]
(* (-b c + a d)^2 + (a c + b d)^2 == (a^2 + b^2) (c^2 + d^2) *)

(This output obfuscates the Inactive[Equal], but note that in the FullForm of the output expression, Equal is replaced by Inactive[Equal].)
Then one can Activate the expression to evaluate it:
Activate@expr // Simplify
(* True *)


(a c + b d)^2 + (a d - b c)^2 // Simplify

